# How do you calculate a full quartic force field for anharmonic frequencies?

Tags: computational-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, vibrations, many-body-perturbation-theory

I am an experimental chemist interested in anharmonicity—I am particularly interested in how to calculate anharmonic frequencies. The method I have the most experience with is (generalised) second order vibrational perturbation theory (G)VPT2.

In most programs where VPT2 is implemented (if not all), the full quadratic (harmonic) and cubic, and semi-quartic force fields are determined. This is because, while *all* quadratic and cubic force constants ($\phi_{ijk}$) are used to calculate the anharmonicity constants $x_{ii}$ and $x_{ij}$, the only quartic force constants which contribute are $\phi_{iiii}$ and $\phi_{iijj}$.$^1$

Practically speaking, my understanding of this approach is that, following harmonic frequency calculations for a molecule (where the hessian/second derivatives has/have been calculated analytically), two further hessians are calculated for each vibrational mode to either side of the equilibrium geometry along the vibration's normal coordinate [i.e., 2(2N – 6) additional hessians are calculated]. From the analytical hessians, the cubic and semi-quartic force fields would be calculated numerically.

The issue with calculating a semi-quartic force field is that, if one wanted to look at the frequencies of different isotopologues of molecules, a second VPT2 calculation would have to be run; my understanding is that the same force fields could be used if a full quartic force field had been determined initially.

So, if I wanted to calculate the *full* quartic force field, what additional calculations would need to be run? Would it just be a case of calculating more hessians along the normal coordinates of each vibration, or would implementation of analytical third derivatives be required, or something else entirely?

1. Wilson Jr., E. B.; Decius, J. C.; Cross, P. C., *Molecular Vibrations*; Dover Publications, Inc.: New York, 1980.

Comment: I suppose you are speaking about bond and angle anharmonic terms, since dihedrals usually are already treated anharmonically? As far as I understand, at each displaced geometry you evaluate energy plus all the available analytical derivatives up to order $n$ to use them in your objective function for minimisation of the difference between QM and MM data. Finally, you could maybe consider introducing off-diagonal terms in your force-field to introduce couplings between internal coordinates?

Comment: @Anon I’m not quite sure what you are suggesting. VPT2 doesn’t use any MM data; it’s an entirely QM method (when I use it, at least). And the off-diagonal terms *are* used in VPT2; in fact, the point of GVPT2 is to correct some of the problems that arise when couplings become too strong between different vibrations (VPT2 does not address these inherently, so some terms can ‘blow up’ and give very strange frequencies).

Comment: Then I'm not sure what you mean by quartic force field. From the question it seems that you want to obtain MM parameters to describe anharmonically some terms of the potential that are usually described as harmonic. I clearly misunderstood your question.

Comment: @Anon perhaps *I'm* misunderstanding... I'm assuming by 'MM' you mean 'molecular mechanics', as in the context of QM:MM methods, like ONIOM calculations? In which case, MM-style force fields (which is what I *assume* you are referring to) are not involved. The VPT2 calculations I am talking about are entirely ab initio- or DFT-based.

Comment: Yeah, I meant MM as in molecular mechanics because you spoke about force fields, but I misunderstood, apparently.

Comment: Please refrain from getting into back and forth edit/rollback wars. If you feel strongly about a particular edit (e.g. content of a post, potential new tags), make a post on the Meta site to gauge community opinion.

Comment: Also, if you do want to make a brand new tag (for example, if the 400+ tag options that we already have are not enough), another place you can make the suggestion is in our [tags chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107328/tags).

Comment: @NikeDattani the tag was perfectly fine earlier (I even wrote a short description which was successfully peer reviewed). I'm sorry if that offends you, but it's a tag that describes the particular subject that this question pertains to. Just because after I made an unrelated edit one day and you noticed it and don't like it does not give you the right to remove it after it had been approved by someone else. You might want to consider the fact that you are the only one trying to force this change, clearly against my judgement, without any explanation or justification for your decision.

Comment: @Tyberius considering the meta site is almost exclusively used by the person who wants the change, what exactly would that achieve? Wouldn't it make more sense to let me have my edit, block Nike from being allowed to edit my posts, and see if anyone else tries to make the same change? That would be a *true* test of community opinion. Most people here have the reputation required to make these edits, but only Nike thinks it should be changed. After I made the tag the first time, I added a description/blurb for it, which was peer reviewed and accepted, so *someone* else thinks it's reasonable.

Comment: @isolatedmatrix [I accidentally approved your tag wiki description](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/3057) before I realized that it was a single-use tag. [Your next tag edit was rejected by the community](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/3067). The people who gave "approve" votes have comparatively nearly zero experience on this site and don't know why it's important not to have descriptions on single-use tags here. Any further comments would only be appropriate on Meta, or [Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107328/tags).